# POST не получает переданные данные

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

Взялся доделывать проект заказчика. Он написан на Yii2( знаний о данном фреймворке -  0 ).

В нем есть скрипт по подбору города в зависимости от введенных символов ( вводишь К и тебе выдается список городов где есть буква К ).

js обработчик

```
    if($('#select-city-2').is('select')){
        var $cities = $('#select-city-2');
            
        $cities.select2({
            dropdownCssClass: 'citiy-container'
        });
        $('body').on('keyup','.citiy-container#select2-drop input', function(){
            var q = $(this).val();
            
            var country = $('#select-country-2 :selected').val();
            if(country == 0) {
                country = 1;
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: 'get=city&q=' +q + '&country=' + country,
                url: '/user/get-location',
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $cities.html(response);
                }
            });
            
            
            
        })
        
    }
```

php обработчик

```
    /* @var $this yii\web\View */
        /* @var $form yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm */
        /* @var $model \frontend\models\SignupForm */
    
        use yii\helpers\Html;
        use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
    
        $q = $_POST['q'];
        $cities = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/api.php?oauth=1&method=database.getCities&v=5.120&need_all=1&count=10&access_token=c7dc6f4fc7dc6f4fc7dc6f4ff7c7b5eaa0cc7dcc7dc6f4f9b4634656985b48c1c122992&country_id=1&q=" . $q);
print_r('qqqqqq');
```

`file_get_contents` - делает запрос к VK API и получает список 10 городов, ссылка - рабочая, но это и не важно. Проблема в том, что при написании любого `print_r` с любым содержимым, response всегда пустой. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

```
 /* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $form yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm */
/* @var $model \frontend\models\SignupForm */

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;

$q = $_POST['q'];
$cities = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/api.php?oauth=1&method=database.getCities&v=5.120&need_all=1&count=10&access_token=c7dc6f4fc7dc6f4fc7dc6f4ff7c7b5eaa0cc7dcc7dc6f4f9b4634656985b48c1c122992&country_id=1&q=" . $q);
```

Вы ничего не возвращаете, результат вроде надо вернуть.

Comment: "Проблема в том, что при написании любого print_r с любым содержимым, response всегда пустой"

Comment: А код точно в методе контроллера находится, он у вас по ходу во вьюхе находится.?

Comment: Господи, не знаю, мне новый вопрос создавать или как. Зашел в контроллер, там был данный метод, но старая версия API указана, поменял, все заработало. Я вообще не понимаю как работает этот фреймворк, тут же в скрипте нигде явно не писался вызов данного метода... Огромное вам спасибо за наводку!

Comment: Фреймвор не так уж и плохо, правда там много магии, а так все хорошо рад, что у вас получилось